# Como adicionar uma funcionalidade ao jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho algumas funções prontas que formatam data, pegam somente números de strings, bloqueiam os campos para não permitir letras etc. Exemplos:

```
function formatarData(data){
    // conteúdo da função
    return data;
}

function somenteNumeros(campo){
    // conteúdo da função
}
```

Como faço para agregar isso ao jQuery de forma que funcione assim:

```
var dataFormatada = $("#data").val().formatarData();
$("#cpf").somenteNumeros();
```

Minha intenção é ter um jQuery personalizado para que eu reutilize em minhas aplicações.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550866/how-to-create-custom-jquery-function-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: Resolve isso com [jQuery fn extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando oque fora comentado pelos amigos acima o `jQuery.fn.extend` restringe as extensões as nodes do jQuery resumindo as extensões somente serão aplicáveis a elementos do tipo jQuery portanto você não poderia utilizar as respectivas depois de utilizar o método `$('seletor').val()` qual retorna uma string, a invocação correta seria `$('seletor').funcao()` onde a função retornaria a string.

Exemplo:

```js
$.fn.formatarData = function() {
  // conteúdo da função
  return this.val();
};

$.fn.somenteNumeros = function() {
  // conteúdo da função
  return this.val();
  
};



alert($('.data').formatarData());
alert($('.cpf').somenteNumeros());

// conforme alertado acima a instrução abaixo retornaria uma exception porque a função
// formatarData está atrelada somente a nodes da jQuery e o resultado o .val() constitui
// uma string.
// alert($('.data').val().formatarData())
// função implementada:

String.prototype.formatarData = function() {
  // conteúdo da função
  return ('string funcao 2 usando val: ' + this);
};

alert($('.data').val().formatarData())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="cpf" value="123.123.123.01" />
<input type="text" class="data" value="16/03/1990" />
```